# DataGridView.Columns.DisplayIndex causes an error 'object reference is not set to an instance of an object' in C# Windows application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have made a Windows forms application using c# and I am trying to add the edit and delete options in my datagridview. I have written the code for reordering of the columns using DisplayIndex as shown below but it throws a NullReferenceException and gives an error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.I have included these statements in the FormName_Load method and I am using Visual Studio Professional 2013.

```
        DataGridViewLinkColumn EditLink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
        EditLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
        EditLink.HeaderText = "Edit";
        //EditLink.DataPropertyName = dataGridView1.ToString();
        EditLink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
        EditLink.Text = "edit";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(EditLink);
        dataGridView1.Columns["Edit"].DisplayIndex = 9;
        //dataGridView1.Columns["Edit"].Visible = true;
```

Comment: See following link: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), the `DisplayIndex` property is zero based, and corresponds to the current position of the column as displayed by the user interface.

Are you certain that

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Edit"].DisplayIndex = 9;
```

is in the range of valid indexes?

Comment: But I want to put the edit and delete columns after the 9th column in the table......so logically speaking the index should be 9